# Massively delete files with common prefix in terminal Mac OS X

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, batch-rename

### I have a bunch of images like this:

[image]

I want to erase them all except those without the suffixes *(-150x150, -256x256, etc)*.

For example, looking at the image above I want to keep only `bg_section_2.jpg`, `bg_section_bw.jpg` and `bg_section_half_2.jpg` and delete the others with prefixes.

> The **numbers** of the sizes (-150x150...etc) are not the same in all the
>   examples. But they have the same structure.

Many thanks for your time! :)

Comment: How about `rm *x*` or `rm *[0-9]*x[0-9]**`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with find. The `-regex` option takes everything that has one or more numbers `[0-9]+`, followed by an `x`, in turn again followed by one or more numbers `[0-9]+`. Just make sure you test this first by copying the directory and check the results ;-)

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
$ touch {a,b,c}.png; touch {a,b,c}-{10,11}x{150,4000}.png
$ find . -type f -regex '.*[0-9]+x[0-9]+.*' -exec rm {} \;
$ ls
a.png  b.png  c.png
```

As notified by s3cur3 (thanks!), you should add the `-E` flag on Mac:

```sh
$ find -E . -type f -regex '.*[0-9]+x[0-9]+.*' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: I do not own a Mac, but I've tested this with GNU find on Debian 9.

Comment: On Mac, you'll need the `-E` flag for "extended (modern) regular expression patterns, rather than basic regular expressions." Full command then looks like: `$ find -E . -type f -regex '.*[0-9]+x[0-9]+.*' -exec rm {} \;`